# Calling DeleteLocalRef() generates "JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local 0x19"

Tags: android, java-native-interface

This code fragment:

```
void tester(JNIEnv *env, const std::string &header)
{
    jstring jniHeader = env->NewStringUTF(header.c_str());
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jniHeader);
}
```

generates these log messages:

```
2022-01-31 20:35:25.930 17257-17342/com.example.myapplication E/x.myapplicatio: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local 0x19  (index 1 in a table of size 1)
2022-01-31 20:35:25.930 17257-17342/com.example.myapplication A/x.myapplicatio: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x19
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

(This is condensed from a larger program. I've confirmed that the returned jniHeader value is valid.)

Comment: Is that the actual code that you're running that's generating that error? If not, please put together a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of a really massive system. I added that test function as shown to illustrate the problem, but it looks like I'd better write a stand-alone test. Stand by ...

Comment: It's also highly threaded, so I suspect that the problem lies there.

Comment: *Sigh*. Turns out that it only happens while single-stepping in the debugger. I think I'll let this go for now.